Need help understanding how vector calculation works in gdscipt
I'm just getting started with gdscript and I'm trying to understand this simple movement function.

    extends CharacterBody2D
    
    @export var speed = 400
    
    func get_input():
        var input_direction = Input.get_vector("left", "right", "up", "down")
        velocity = input_direction * speed
        print(input_direction)
        print(velocity)
    
    func _physics_process(delta):
        get_input() 
        move_and_slide()

My First Doubt:
If I, for example, move left, input_direction prints (-1,0) and velocity prints (-400,0).
I know it's multiplying the 400 (Speed) by -1, but how? What is the datatype being returned by get_vector(...) that is able to multiply both parameters if I multiply it by its return value?
Would something like Vector3(0, 0, 2) * 2 multiply all parameters by two?
My Second Doubt:
When I go up left, input_direction prints: (-0.707107, 0.707107)
and the velocity prints: (-282.8427, 282.8427)
What is the correlation between my inputs and these numerical outputs?

Take a look at the documentation for Input.get_vector. This shows the return type is Vector2. Clicking through to the Vector2 class has links describing how vectors work.

The 3b1b course that is linked in the documentation is a great resource and should explain the concepts here.

thanks a lot guys, I found the following link which explains the godot math basics
https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/math/vector_math.html
It also links to this khan academy course on linear algebra
https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra
